# Chamar bindValue por $this->... ou direto pelo $_SESSION?

Tags: php, pdo

O código aonde está a minha dúvida é o seguinte..

```
public function queryFixClayTime($data) {
        if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
            session_start();
        }
        if ($_SESSION['claytime'] >= $_SESSION['clayhour']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
            // 
        } else {
            try {
                $this->iduser = $data['iduser'];
                $this->timeplus = $_SESSION['claytimeplus']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $cst = $this->con->connect()->prepare("UPDATE resources SET claytime = :claytime WHERE iduser = :iduser");
                $cst->bindValue(":claytime", $this->timeplus);
                $cst->bindValue(":iduser", $this->iduser);
                $cst->execute();
                $id['iduser'] = $_SESSION['iduser'];
                $objupdate = new Resources();
                $objupdate->querySelectResource($id);
            } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

O foco é aqui:

```
$cst->bindValue(":claytime", $this->timeplus);
$cst->bindValue(":iduser", $this->iduser);
```

Fazer da maneira acima funciona perfeitamente

E assim também...

```
$cst->bindValue(":claytime", $_SESSION['claytimeplus']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$cst->bindValue(":iduser", $_SESSION['iduser']);
```

Qual é a diferença entre usar o `$this->iduser` ou o `$_SESSION['iduser']`

Usar o `$_SESSION` direto é uma má prática de programação ? E de alguma forma pode deixar o código mais inseguro ?

Comment: De que forma os valores do `$this` são definidos? Não é a partir de `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Sim, por isso a dúvida, qual a diferença entre usar o $this ou o $_SESSION direto no bindValue ? ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende de como foi feito, se, ao definir as variáveis em `$this`, não passou por nenhum processo de sanitização, validação, etc, do ponto de vista da segurança é o mesmo, afinal, você só adicionou o valor em outro ponto da memória e a acessou por ele

Quanto a boas práticas, também depende, se os valores forem recebidos no construtor (ou alguma função/método que retorne um objeto da classe), seu código seria menos acoplado, alterações na origem dos dados (por exemplo, passou a usar `$_GET` ao invés de `$_SESSION`) não alteram a classe. Desacoplamento também costuma ajudar a testar unitariamente o código. Mas isso também implica mais complexidade, se sua classe não precisar guardar estado, você não precisa dela, apenas funções deixaria o código mais simples